# REGEXP: Find word directly followed by other word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
match ddd green dd match ddd red d match ddddddd yellow ddd match dd red ddddddd match dddd blue ddd match ddd yellow d match ddddd red
```

I want to find all `match` words that are followed by the word `red` until the next `match` occurs. In this case the 2nd, 4th and 7th `match` should be found.

How can this be done with javascript regexp?

Comment: Didn't you try anything? Please share the code you have so far to better clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If there had been any useful result in the meantime I would have posted it. I thought that the solution could be a "negative lookahead", but it did not work at all. My work would confuse you more than link to a solution...

Comment: I think you could use [`match(?=(?:(?!match).)*red)`](https://regex101.com/r/nI2lI6/1). But I see you already have a verbose solution.

Comment: And the best is [`match(?=[^m]*(?:m(?!atch)[^m]*)*red)`](https://regex101.com/r/nI2lI6/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought to respond this is: begin with splitting string into chunks beginning with "match". Then it's totally obvious to see which chunks satisfiy the condition "is followed by "red".

The above solution is pretty simple to write in javascript. Something like this:

```
var string = 'match ddd green dd match ddd red d match ddddddd yellow ddd match dd red ddddddd match dddd blue ddd match ddd yellow d match ddddd red',
    chiefWord = 'match',
    follower = 'red',
    chunks = string.split(new RegExp(chiefWord + '\\s+')),
    result = [];
for (var i = 0, n = chunks.length; i < n; i++) {
  if (chunks[i].indexOf(follower) >= 0) {
    result.push(i); // or chunks[i], or any other way to express result
  }
}
console.log(result); // reports "[2, 4, 7]"
```

Comment: Splitting up the string and than search the array is the right idea. Thanks.

Comment: @heinob. In my mind this solution was not totally right, because it didn't use _only_ regexp. But of course I'm glad you like it.

Comment: The question was "with regexp", not "only with regexp" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help? It uses `exec` to mark where those matches are in the string:

```
var regex = /(match) [a-z]+ red/gi
var myArray;
while ((myArray = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  var msg = 'Found match at character ' +  myArray.index;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Found match at character 19
Found match at character 60
Found match at character 120
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/p2pf31at/)